Decrement on type null has no effect, this will change in the next major version
This code has worked in previous versions of PHP for years:
function dayOfWeek ($day, $month, $year)
{
    // ...
    if ($month < 3) {
        $month += 10;
        $year--;  // **24 line**
    }
    else {
        $month -= 2;
    }
    // ...
}

However, since upgrading to PHP 8.3 I sometimes get this warning when I call it:

Warning: Decrement on type null has no effect, this will change in the
next major version of PHP in /home/gagebu/www/calendar.php on line 24

How should I edit the code to resolve this warning?

Have you tried checking if the variable is null before trying to decrement it? Have you made any attempt to amend it yourself?

As the message clearly says, you are calling the function with a null value for the $year parameter, which should not happen.

Is there something specific about the warning message which you were struggling to understand? If so you should mention it, so we can help you with that. Did you do any research? See also [ask]

You need add code to check if the year is null (and for any of the others, if they're all required fields) and then either substitute a default value (if appropriate) or perhaps throw an error - the choice is yours obviously, but you certainly need to do something, because trying to subtract from null makes no sense at all...hence the warning. PHP was more tolerant of this kind of nonsense in the past, and you had to live with your own mistakes if you didn't spot them, but now it's  trying to make people write better code.

I've edited to clarify the question, but it still lacks detail on how the code was being called to trigger this error. This should be added as an [edit] to the question so it can better help future visitors.

PHP has long been trying to clean up some of the mess caused by its inherent weak typing, and this is no exception. This was changed per this RFC, which notes something unexpected happens with trying to increment vs decrement null
$x = $y = null;
$x++;
var_dump($x); // 1
$y--;
var_dump($y); // NULL

That's inconsistent behavior. Instead, PHP is going to expect you to pass something numeric in the future.
To fix your code, just add a check for null. I've added the current year, but you can add your own default value
function dayOfWeek ($day, $month, $year)
{
    if($year === null) $year = date('Y');
    if ($month < 3) {
        $month += 10;
        $year--;  // **24 line**
    }
    else {
        $month -= 2;
    }
}


"To fix your code, just add a check for null" It would be better to know why the function is called with null, and fix the caller. The correct value might be next year, not the current one, we don't know.

@Olivier I tend to agree, but we were only given the function code, and it may not be as easy a thing to fix upstream (i.e. a query can return a null, and it might not be easy to find all queries that do that). Some updated PHP conventions have forced me to do a local change in this manner.

Sure, but if the OP (which obviously has low PHP skills) reads your answer, they will just copy/paste the code and believe that the issue is now fixed. I wrote the comment so that they know it may not be as simple.

Now I know that null-- is still null. Since the code has worked for 20 years, then the null value is intended, at least your fix violates the intention.

@shingo I'm not sure what you mean. We're not shown what it does with $year so assuming it's a null may not be what it's supposed to do.

We are not shown. But I prefer to assume that $year is null as its original intention (maybe as an unused argument), otherwise the entire code should contain more warnings and errors caused by the null value. You replaced it with the current year, I think it is more likely to produce an unexpected result.

$year ??= date('Y'); would work in place of if($year === null) $year = date('Y'); (conditionals without braces scare me)
